# How to explicitly instantiate the template function in the template class?

Tags: c++

b.h:

```
#ifndef CCC
#define CCC

template<typename T>
class C
{
    public: template<typename T1> void F(T1 t1);
};

#endif
```

b.cc:

```
#include "b.h"

#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

template<typename T>
template<typename T1>
void C<T>::F(T1 t1)
{
    cout<<t1<<endl;
}
```

a.cc:

```
#include "b.h"

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    C<int> c;
    c.F(1.0f);
}
```

make.sh:

```
#!/bin/bash
g++ b.cc -fPIC -shared -o b.so -std=c++1y
g++ a.cc b.so -o a.out -std=c++1y
```

g++ output:

```
/tmp/ccYLnd28.o: In function `main':
a.cc:(.text+0x1f): undefined reference to `void C<int>::F<float>(float)'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

It seems that explicit instantiation of the function "F" is needed, when a and b are compiled seperately. How?

Comment: Do you mean specialize?

Comment: No, not specialization. I mean the explicit instantialization of a template function in a template class.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you have a coding error.  T1 is not defined in templated class C.  If you want your return value and argument to be a different type, T1, it must named it in the template specification.  Or you simply have a typo. Either of the following code will work depending on the intent

```
template<typename T>
class C  
{  
    template<typename T> 
    T F(T t)  
    {  
         return t;  
    }  
}
```

or

```
template<typename T, T1>
class C  
{  
    template<typename T, T1> 
    T1 F(T1 t)  
    {  
         return t;  
    }  
}
```

The first snippet takes in an int and returns an int.  I works when you pass in a  float because C++ will automatically convert float's to int's, so you will get an int back. Per the function specification.

The second snippet takes in a float, and returns a float.  You have to modify your main to specify the second templated argument as such

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    C<int, float> c;
    c.F(1.0);
}
```

Comment: Two slight things: In the first one, `F()` shouldn't be a templated function, because it can use `C`'s template parameter `T`: `T F(T t);`  In the second one, while both `T` and `T1` can be `C`'s template parameters (with the same rule as before), it makes more sense for `T` to be `C`'s parameter and `T1` to be `F()`'s parameter: `template<typename T> class C`, and `template<typename T1> T1 F(T1 t);`.  See [here](http://ideone.com/9StZ9r) for an example.